# How do I pass multiple entry_points to polymer transformer in pubspec.yaml?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Now that `pub build` supports building Polymer apps, how do I pass multiple entry_points to the Polymer transformer in my pubspec.yaml file?

When I try to build with this syntax both files have errors:

```yaml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/reports.html, web/index.html
```

And when I try passing them in the following manner, only the last listed entry point is built:

```yaml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
    entry_points: web/reports.html
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [YAML, a sequence](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2802662) is created by wrapping a comma separated list in square brackets `[ 0, 1, 2, ]` or by putting each entry on a line by itself prepended by a hyphen `-` So your example would look like this:

```yaml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: [ web/index.html, web/reports.html ]
```

Or this:

```yaml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: 
      - web/index.html
      - web/reports.html
```

Comment: Is having multiple entry points ideal? I created a multiple entry point application and I seem to notice, when call an entry point, it takes a bit of time to load.

Comment: Not ideal, or even common. Dart is generally used for single page applications. Occasionally however there may be a separate entry point for an application, such as an admin interface or other similar logic that you don't want directly tied into the main application itself.