# How do you use polymer for dart as javascript?

Tags: javascript, dart, polymer, dart2js

I've got the dart-sdk, updated my path to include the dart binaries, downloaded the [tutorials](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples) and grabbed its dependencies by running "pub get".  I'm going to lean toward using dart2js until dartium integrates fully with chromium, and using

```
dart2js clickme.dart -o clickme.dart.js
```

works fine from Firefox (I'm working in vim and not the Dart Editor or Spark).

But tutes using polymer don't include a main() so dart2js won't compile them.  I'm not sure how to proceed.  I don't know how to create an instance of TuteStopwatch, which extends PolymerElement, which might be used to create a main(), for example.

Answer (score 0):

A more comfortable (IMHO) way to build is using 'pub build'.
For Polymer you need to configure a transformer in pubspec.yaml.

see [How do I pass multiple entry_points to polymer transformer in pubspec.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147030)

Comment: Ok, but steps specific to the stopwatch tutorial would be more helpful.  I noticed a dart-tutorials-samples-master/web/to-polymer-notes.txt but I couldn't get far with the instructions.

Comment: The file you mention is about converting from PolymerDart predecessor WebUI to PolymerDart. When you are looking for an introduction to PolymerDart look here https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/